# PHP date function in local timezone and NOW in UTC

Tags: php

In my code, `$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` returns the time in UTC. But when using UPDATE to inject let say `'last_login' = NOW()`, it returns the time according to my timezone. This posts problem when you want to compare between the two time. I want to keep things in UTC, so is there a way to UPDATE the 'last_login' field in UNIX or UTC time as well?

Comment: Because PHP an MySql on your server are using different timezones

Comment: Hanky Panky, you're the man. I thought PHP and MySql were essentially the same. Your response makes me realize everything makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$now=gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

gmdate() is identical to date but with GMT time

Comment: Thanks, the $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") is already in GMT. I need a way to update the last_login field = NOW() to GMT.

Comment: $last_login=gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s"); it will return the same result as NOW() with the same format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time());
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Athul. But I actually need the last_logon = NOW() to update in UTC.  The now() update the last_login field in local timezone. I need the now() to return UTC.